# How to make Raven DB Lucene query work with result transformer

Tags: ravendb

I have a RavenDB Linq query that uses a result transformer working properly that I am attempting to convert to Lucene syntax in order to facilitate creating dynamic queries.  However, I am unable to get the Lucene query to work correctly and am looking for some guidance.

**Result Transformer:**

```
public class CallRecordWithDisplayNameTransformer : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<CallRecord>
{
  public CallRecordWithDisplayNameTransformer()
  {
    TransformResults = callRecords => from callRecord in callRecords
      let displayNameRecord = LoadDocument<DisplayName>(callRecord.PhoneNumber)
      let displayName = (displayNameRecord != null) ? displayNameRecord.Name : string.Empty
      select new{
        CallRecord = callRecord,
        DisplayName = displayName
      };
  }
}
```

**The result class that is created by the transformer:**

```
public class CallRecordWithDisplayName
{
  public CallRecord CallRecord { get; set; }
  public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Linq query that works successfully (when this query is executed 25 of the fully populated & transformed 'CallRecordWithDisplayName' objects are returned):

```
session.Query<CallRecord>()
    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.CallDateTime)
    .TransformWith<CallRecordWithDisplayNameTransformer, CallRecordWithDisplayName>()
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(25)
    .ToList();
```

Here is the Lucene query that does not work correctly.  When this query is executed it returns 25 **null** instances of 'CallRecord' objects, not the 'CallRecordWithDisplayName' objects that are created by the transformer.

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<CallRecord>()
  .OrderByDescending("CallDateTime")
  .Skip(0)
  .Take(25)
  .SetResultTransformer(new CallRecordWithDisplayNameTransformer().TransformerName)
  .ToList();
```

Here are the server logs that show the queries that are being sent to the server for the Linq (request #584) and Lucene (request #585) requests:

```
Request # 584: GET     -     7 ms - FiddleFlights - 200 - /indexes/dynamic/CallR
ecords?&pageSize=25&sort=-CallDateTime&resultsTransformer=CallRecordWithDisplayN
ameTransformer&operationHeadersHash=525986370
        Query:
        Time: 6 ms
        Index: Auto/xz2MTg77IKTTb7MyHLD/4A==
        Results: 25 returned out of 597 total.

Request # 585: GET     -     7 ms - FiddleFlights - 200 - /indexes/dynamic/CallR
ecords?&pageSize=25&sort=-CallDateTime&resultsTransformer=CallRecordWithDisplayN
ameTransformer
        Query:
        Time: 5 ms
        Index: Auto/xz2MTg77IKTTb7MyHLD/4A==
        Results: 25 returned out of 597 total.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a static index of your CallRecords and call it like this:

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<CustomerNameViewModel, Customers_ByName>()
    .OrderByDescending("Name")
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(25)
    .SetResultTransformer(new CustomerNameTransformer().TransformerName)
    .ToList();
```

Edit: Or use the Auto index like this:

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<CustomerNameViewModel>("Auto/Customers/ByName")
```

Where Customer in my case is your CallRecord.

This works for me in RavenDB 3.0.3599, however, if you're using 3.0 you should use DocumentQuery<> instead of LuceneQuery as the latter is obsolete (but it works).

However, I'm not sure this is the "correct" way to do it, but I can't find another way of defining the return type of the Transformer when used with .SetResultTransformer(...)

Hope this helps!

Edit: Here's my transformer, built with weird LoadDocument just to test. so it  doesn't make any "real" sense:

```
public class CustomerNameTransformer : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<Customer>
{
    public CustomerNameTransformer()
    {
        TransformResults = results => from customer in results
                                      let fixture = LoadDocument<Fixture>(customer.FixtureNumber)
                                      select new CustomerNameViewModel
                                      {
                                          Id = customer.Id,
                                          Name = customer.Name,
                                          FixtureNumber = fixture.FixtureNumber,
                                          Customer = customer
                                      };
    }
}
```

Comment: Jaynard, in your example what is the return type of the Transformer?